# What is the meaning of " let me stop you there "?

Tags: meaning

A good many times I have come across the sentence "Let me stop you there". What does it mean?

Comment: You need to show us you have used a dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

> Let me stop you there

means that the person who says those words has decided that what you are saying is demonstrably wrong and wishes to pose a rebuttal before you continue laying out your statement or argument.

Note that this can be fairly rude, so in a conversation with a stranger, say, you'd be advised not to use it.

Answer (score 1):

It means:

> Let me interrupt you and tell you something.

It is an idiomatic way of interrupting the other party with the intention of giving new information that might surprise or contradict the other person.

Comment: RE: “It means what it says literally” – it could be construed to mean a couple different things _literally_. (It could mean that I’m ready to tackle you on the sidewalk, for example.)

Comment: @J.R. That's a fair point. I will revise my answer.